# Customize edit form of library with InfoPath

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, designer-workflow, library

In lists it is possible to customize the form with InfoPath. For libraries this function is missing.

Is there any way to use an InfoPath form to edit data in a library? I know that it's possible to display a form as an additional web part (Library -> Customize Library -> Form Web Parts), but I couldn't figure out a way to actually submit data to the library within the form.

My aim is to start a designer workflow with the data entered in the InfoPath form.

Comment: Short answer is - no, you cant modify the forms for a document library. I think however that you can create one with code.

Comment: Is there a reason for this, which I should know of? As I didn't touch code with SPD, yet: Is it possible to create a similar functionality with it (in regards to rules, cascading dropdowns etc.)?